# I have a deley navigating to the home page react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When opening the app and there is a token it shows the login page for a sec befor going to home page how to stop it from doing so

Code

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);
  // const Token = useSelector((store) => store.userState.userToken);
  const isDarkTheme = useSelector((store) => store.themeState.Theme);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (mounted) {
        if (user) {
          setUserToken(JSON.stringify(user.uid));
        } else {
          setUserToken(null);
        }
      }
    });
    dispatch(getTheme());
    // dispatch(getToken());
    return function cleanup() {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, [userToken]);

  const theme = isDarkTheme ? CustumDarkTheme : CustumDefaultTheme;

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <Provider theme={theme}>
      <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
        {userToken ? (
          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} /> }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigation} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Profile"
              component={Profile}
              options={({}) => ({
                gestureEnabled: true,
                cardOverlayEnabled: true,
                ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
                headerShown: false,
              })}
            />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="PatientDetails"
              component={PatientDetails}
              options={({}) => ({
                gestureEnabled: true,
                cardOverlayEnabled: true,
                ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
                headerShown: false,
              })}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Start" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} />
            <Stack.Screen name="LogIn" component={LogIn} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
```

...................................

I tryed useLayoutEffect and getting the token from the asyncStorge but it allows use the initial state value befor updating the state
..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only solution here would be to have 3 states.

1. auth undefined - blank loading page
2. auth null - login page
3. auth present - logged in page

update the initial state to have undefined -

`const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(undefined);`

then add conditions like -

```
<NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
  {userToken === undefined     ? /** navigator with loader  **/ : null}
  {userToken === null          ? /** navigator with login   **/ : null}
  {typeof userToken === string ? /** navigator with profile **/ : null}
</NavigationContainer>
```

You can have another state variable to hold more defined values, (like `0, 1, 2` for the 3 states). You can decide the implementation details.